# Alguien me explica para que sirve lo siguiente: | Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="serieMod.nombre"/>
```

Me tira el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber para que sirve el ngModelOptions, ya que en este caso con el ngModel directo a la propiedad no funciona.

si agrego [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" **Si funciona**

Quiero saber porque no funciona si esto

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Importaste FormsModule en tu modulo general?

Comment: @AlexisNarvaez ,sisi obvio

Comment: Yo usaría reactive forms para evitar esos comportamientos raros.

Comment: si, generalmente los uso para lo laboral o aplicaciones complejas, para algo simple tipo crud prefiero forms de plantilla son mas rapidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ngModelOptions omite el valor en el formulario. Es decir si el input pertenece a un formulario, este formulario no incluye al input (tanto el dato y la validacíon) que contenga el [standalone](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-a-standalone-ngmodel-within-a-group).

**Edit**

To formulario crea automáticamente un `Formgroup`, entonces por cada `ngModel` con la etiqueta `input`, creará un `FormControl`, este será agregado al `FormGroup` con el nombre especificado en el atributo `name`. En ese caso tienes que declararlo independiente usando `standalone` y no agregarlo al `FormGroup` creado o declaras el atributo `name`.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo, es porque no funciona directamente con el ngModel, sin el ngModelOptions

Comment: @DiegoFerrer en ese caso reformula tu pregunta y compleméntala con el error que mencionas. El `standalone` no tiene relación con el como funciona tu propiedad en el NgModel. Solo sirve para indicar que un control de formulario es *"independiente"*. Esto permite a los desarrolladores marcar que ciertos controles no deben registrarse con el formulario principal si es necesario.

Comment: Ahi lo edite, puse el error y demas

Comment: @DiegoFerrer En ese caso te esta pidiendo que agregues un atributo `name="serieModNombre"` a tu input o lo marques como `standalone`. Te lo detallo mas en la respuesta.

Comment: @DiegoFerrer, actualice la respuesta, espero sea de tu ayuda.